# Where does the collinearity even come from?

Tags: panel-data

Here's the sample data: [Link to a .csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17q7snP4b1dB0K7lXbyAYkQ0aZeEELMCF/view?usp=sharing)

To briefly explain this: `grandparent` is 1 if the individual is a grandparent and 0 if otherwise. `m_age` is the individual's age. `m_work` is the individual's working status and `m_workhour` is the individual's weekly working hours. `child1_female` indicates whether the individual's first child is female. `child_number` is the number of children that the individual has.

I try to use `fixest` package to do instrumental variable fix effects regression. The variable `grandparent` is endogenous and its instrument is `child1_female`. The outcome variable is `m_work`. However, if I add `m_age` as the exogenous regressor and use the following code:

```
ivgrandma<-feols(m_work~m_age|respondent_id+year|grandparent~child1_female,grandma)
```

It says that "The endogenous regressor 'fit_grandparent' have been removed because of collinearity (see $collin.var)."

I'm very confused about where the collinearity comes from.

Comment: To clarify, the collinearity problem does not arise if you do not add m_age as an exogenous regressor?

Comment: @stats_model I honestly don't know how not to add `m_age`.

Comment: I am not so familiar with feols because I use the lfe package instead, but if feols works anything like felm, you can do `feols(m_work~1|respondent_id+year|grandparent~child1_female,grandma)`

Comment: This will still not work though: writing up answer right now.

Comment: @stats_model Now this error arrises: The only variable 'fit_grandparent' is collinear with the fixed effects. In such circumstances, the estimation is void.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect now, having looked through the csv that this arises because you are including respondent fixed effects. Note that your instrument, `child1_female`, only varies at the respondent level, so if you have `respondent_id` as a fixed effect, that will absorb all variation in `child1_female`. To see why, remember, including `respondent_id` fixed effects is equivalent to estimating a regression where you add indicator variables corresponding to each unique `respondent_id` as a control. Since `child1_female` takes on the same value for each observation corresponding to the same respondent, these indicators for `respondent_id` will clearly completely predict `child1_female`, hence your collinearity problem.

More generally, whenever you are estimating a panel regression, you will not be able to separately fit coefficients for *any* variable does not exhibit within-individual variation.